# contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html

Cuando presiono el botón de editar puedo cambiar el nombre del elemento, pero también se editan los botones, osea que el usuario va a poder eliminar los botones como si estuviera borrando texto. Me gustaría saber que se puede hacer para evitar esto.

```js
let boton = document.querySelector(".boton");
              let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
              let enlaces = document.getElementsByClassName("enlace");
              let changeName = document.getElementsByClassName("editar");
              let li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        
              boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      
        
                let li = document.createElement("li");
                li.setAttribute("id", "li");
                li.innerHTML =
                  "Contenido " +
                  Math.random() +
                  "<div class='contenedor_icon'><img id='edit' title='editar' class='editar' src='https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/pencil.png'><img class='enlace' src='https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/delete-sign.png'></div>";
        
                contenedor.appendChild(li);
        
                eliminar();
                cambiar_nombre();
              });
        
              function eliminar() {
                for (let i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++) {
                  enlaces[i].onclick = function(e) {
                    let content = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
                    let li = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
                    content.removeChild(li);
                  };
                }
              }
        
              eliminar();
        
              function cambiar_nombre() {
                for (let i = 0; i < changeName.length; i++) {
                  changeName[i].onclick = e => {
                    let li = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
                    li.contentEditable = true;
                    li.focus();
                  };
                }
              }
```

```css
body {
              font-size: sans-serif;
              max-width: 400px;
            }
            #contenedor li {
              padding: 18px;
              margin: 8px 0;
              background: #ddd;
              list-style: none;
            }
            #contenedor li {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: row;
              justify-content: space-between;
            }
        
            .editar {
              margin-right: 10px;
              cursor: pointer;
            }
        
            .contenedor_icon {
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
            }
        
            .enlace {
              cursor: pointer;
            }
        
            .boton {
              cursor: pointer;
            }
```

```html
<body>
            <h1>Como agregar o eliminar elementos a una div</h1>
        
            <div id="contenedor">
              <li id="li">
                Contenido 1
                <div class="contenedor_icon">
                  <img
                    id="edit"
                    class="editar"
                    title="editar"
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/pencil.png"
                  /><img
                    class="enlace"
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/delete-sign.png"
                  />
                </div>
              </li>
              <li id="li">
                Contenido 2
                <div class="contenedor_icon">
                  <img
                    id="edit"
                    class="editar"
                    title="editar"
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/pencil.png"
                  /><img
                    class="enlace"
                    src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/delete-sign.png"
                  />
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
        
            <input
              class="boton"
              type="button"
              value="Agregar elemento"
              style="float: right;"
            />
         </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es tener un elemento con el texto y que sea éste el elemento editable. En lugar de tener

```
<li id="li">
  Contenido 1
  <div class="contenedor_icon">
    <img
      id="edit"
      class="editar"
      src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/pencil.png"
    /><img
      class="enlace"
      src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/delete-sign.png"
    />
  </div>
</li>
```

Puedes tener algo como

```
<li id="li">
  <p class="editable">Contenido 1</p>
  <div class="contenedor_icon">
    <img

      class="editar edit"
      src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/20/000000/pencil.png"
    /><img
      class="enlace"
      src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/delete-sign.png"
    />
  </div>
</li>
```

Y añadir al elemento `<p class="editable">` el atributo `contentEditable` en lugar de a todo el `<li>`.

Por otro lado vigila no usar ID repetidos: no puedes poner a cada imagen el atributo id="edit" porque las búsquedas sólo te encontrarán la primera instancia.

Comment: Cierto, me olvide eliminar esos ID, estaba haciendo pruebas jeje. Y gracias por tu ayuda, SALUDOS!!!